# Passing zlib deflated data from PHP to node.js

Tags: php, node.js, http, zlib

I am trying to deflate a very large string in PHP and pass it over http to a Node server and then inflate it and do some business on it.  My issue is doing the deflate/inflate.

I have tried using PHP gzencode as well as gzcompress passing the string as the ONLY argument. I then try and inflate it in node using one of the following:

```
zlib.inflateSync(new Buffer(attachment.content)).toString()
```

as well as

```
zlib.inflateRawSync(new Buffer(attachment.content)).toString()
```

I have tried every permutation of gzencode/gzompress and zlib.inflateSync/zlig.inflateRawSync.  Anything I try I always get one of two errors from node:

```
Error: incorrect header check
```

or

```
Error: invalid code lengths set
```

I have confirmed that the attachment.content variable contains my gzcompress or gzencode data from php so it isn't an issue of me trying to inflate the wrong variable.  Also, the original string that I am deflating is a large CSV string.  I'm at a loss.

ps.  PHP 5.6.16 and node 0.12.7 (yeah, I know).

Comment: Try to use [Buffer.from()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array) instead of "new Buffer()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gzcompress()` produces a zlib stream, which is compatible with `zlib.inflateSync()`. `gzdeflate()` produces raw deflate, which is compatible with `zlib.inflateRawSync()`. `gzencode()` produces a gzip stream, which is compatible with `zlib.gunzipSync()`.

If above compatible combinations are not working, then most likely the data is being corrupted by a conversion somewhere between the two.

Comment: Turns out the data was being corrupted with my body parser on the Node side of things.  I was originally passing form parameters to Node with one of the form parameters being a gzencoded string.   I ended up gzencoding the entire request and it now works as expected.

Comment: Just a note, that I also had issues with data being corrupted in transfer. I resolved it by encoding the data with  base64_encode, and then on the node.js side using Buffer.from(data, "base64").